# Swift - QR scanner throwing nil error

Tags: ios, swift

I built a QR scanner based on the tutorial [here](http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-reader-swift/). When the app runs, I can see the scanner and when pointed at QR code, the correct text is displayed on screen. Now I want to have a button (Proceed) that will allow me to transition the text value scanned (usernameScanned) to next view controller This is not working and when I press the button, the app crashes with this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

This is the code I have where I store the text into the usernameScanned variable:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
        if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRectZero
            usernameLabel.text = "No barcode/QR code is detected"
            return
        }

        // Get the metadata object.
        let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        // Here we use filter method to check if the type of metadataObj is supported
        // Instead of hardcoding the AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, we check if the type
        // can be found in the array of supported bar codes.
        if supportedBarCodes.contains(metadataObj.type) {
            //        if metadataObj.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {
            // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
            let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadataObj)
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds

            if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
                usernameLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue
                self.usernameScanned = metadataObj.stringValue!
                print(self.usernameScanned)
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is the button proceed action:

```
@IBAction func proceedPressed(sender: AnyObject)
    {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("viewUserProfileForQR", sender: self)
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint and show the line where the crash occurs

Comment: check your segue name in storyboard is `viewUserProfileForQR` exist

Comment: @Paulw11 it only occurs when I press the button and inside the function as can be seen above is only one line. Where would you recommend placing the breakpoint in this case?

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint from the breakpoint navigator. Don't set it on a specific line

Comment: Try commenting out this line qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds from a quick scan this could be the cause

Comment: @DogCoffee tried that but nothing changed

Comment: @Paulw11 not sure what that means as I've not done it before

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html - select stop on all exceptions

Comment: If you still are struggling here is another example QR scanner app https://github.com/humberaquino/SwiftBarcode/blob/master/BarcodeViewController.swift

Comment: @DogCoffee I tried the new example but same error comes up which helps conclude issue may not be in how we are reading but rather the transition of the views...totally still clueless

Comment: After button press is the segueing to the viewUserProfileForQR screen ? Do you have any vars in the 2nd view that are not being set up ? ie var userNameProfile:String! Are you using perform with segue to pass the details you want to show in screen 2 ?

Comment: @DogCoffee YES! that was it! Post as answer and I will choose it. Apparently there was a check that was failing early in the next view controller. Thanks

Comment: Nice - glad to assist

Comment: @DogCoffee thanks but don't forget to include your recommendation as an answer so that others can avoid reading all the comments and find the answer immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the code you posted is not throwing the error, try checking the view controller that you are trying to segue to once you press the button.

You may have variables that are not being instantiated, for example

`var userNameProfile:String!`

Within your `prepareForSegue` method it appears to me that you want to show the result of the scan (its a detail view after all) - so you should pass that value from VC1 to VC2 in this method.